# How to model a relationship between Sandwiches and Toppings?

Tags: database-design

I want to create a database structure pertaining to my *product*, which is a `sandwich` that can have **one** `bread` and **many** `toppings`.

To illustrate the problem I created a [quick diagram](http://image.prntscr.com/image/ad7fcc3d0ce740949b15e32d93e9a442.png):

[image: Diagram]

For the one *bread* I can easily assign the `sandwich_id` as seen in the picture, but how would I assign the many *toppings* in a beautiful way?

**My current considerations**

I could think of some ideas:

`topping_1_id`, etc... and a *toppings* index as in `1` is `‘cheese’`, `5` is `‘onion’`, so `topping_id = 15`, but I am not sure how to do that.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have your `toppings` and `sandwiches` tables, I'd create a linking table consisting of `sandwich_id` and `topping_id`, so that you can `JOIN` from each sandwich record to its many toppings and *vice versa*.

Each link represents a particular sandwich having a particular topping.

Hope that makes sense.